# Double-entry accounting example for Christmas gift from family member

Tags: accounting, double-entry

A family member, Sandra, pays $10 as a Christmas gift for Joe's daughter, Anne. Joe is learning accounting and records the entry as follows. Joe wants to check if the following entries are correct or if any mistakes in classifying the entries as Debit/Credit accounts. Are these classified correctly?

*Note:* Joe maintains a "Gifts Reciprocating" amount as a way to track gifts from family members so he can reciprocate in kind when the opportunity arises.

Journal Entries:

| Debit Account | Amount | Credit Account | Amount | Memo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cash | $10 | Anne Christmas Holdings | $10 | Sandra paid for Anne Christmas presents |
| Gifts from Sandra | $10 | Gifts Reciprocating | $10 | Sandra paid for Anne's Christmas presents |

Thanks.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/145957/104045) to a similar question hold the key

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in accounting and I am learning myself, but I would not classify the gift as a liability towards the family member donating.
While morally you may feel obligated to reciprocate, you don't really have to match the exact amount if and when you'll do so, nor you have an exact date within which doing so.
I believe a better way is to classify the gifts as income/revenue. I'd debit the cash account and credit the income/revenues one.
If you want to track who donated what, you can open a different sub-account per each family member and record the gift under that account.
This is what I do in my personal case.
Happy to be corrected if this is not principled.